# How can I export auto-suppression list rows from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to export the list of rows from my auto-suppression list, how can I do this? It is not available as a DE so Data Extracts wont work.

Comment: Is this a standard suppression list, or the auto-suppression configuration managed within Administration?

Comment: auto-suppression as mentioned in my post above :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple SQL to grab the data from the suppression list and import it to a DE and then export the DE:

```
select [email address]
from [autosuppression list name]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Deployment Failure  export manually if you click on check box what you need data then export the file [image: see this picture you can get some clarify]

Comment: I’m a system admin but I don’t have the button displayed, can you tell me what permission is required for this?

Comment: @Deployment  you are telling Failure check box not showing?

Comment: No I am saying the "Export" button is not displayed and was wondering if there is a permission that I need to enable to see it. FYI This is a auto-suppression list and not a normal suppression list.